# PHP MySQL search & show row by html <input>

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML form like:

```
<form  action = "get-row.php"  method = "post" >                  
<input type = "text"  name = "mess_username" />
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" />
</form>
```

And my "get-row.php" is like :

```
$button = $_POST ['submit'];
$search = $_POST ['mess_username'];

if (!$button) {
    echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
}
else {
    if (strlen($search) <= 1) {
        echo "Search term too short";
    }
    else {
        echo "You searched for <b> $search </b> <hr size='1' >";
    }
}
```

I am now successfully getting the value I have searched for. My next approach is to search the $search from my Database. I am trying like:

```
mysql_connect("server", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("my_db");
```

My Final "ok" Code after currection :

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM messbd WHERE mess_username= '$search' ";
$run = mysql_query($sql);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b> $search </b>";
}
else {
    echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

    while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
        $mess_username = $runrows ['mess_username'];
        $mess_email = $runrows ['mess_email'];
        $android_app = $runrows ['android_app'];

        echo " $mess_username  <br> $mess_email <br> $android_app ";
    }
}
```

The problem is, I am getting the message that, "There are no matching results!" So what will be the correction there?

The problem is solved now & The code is updated above. Thanks.

Comment: Proobably nothing but is `messbd` the name of your database? I would *think* you maybe meant `messdb`?

Comment: @JeremyHarris Yes! `messbd` is the name of my database. Thanks.

Comment: Try to check for errors with `mysql_error` or simply check what contains in  `$foundnum` vriable. If all ok with your query - I guess you have to add your DB structure to question.

Also use `mysql_real_escape_string` on your query `$sql` and I think manual article http://php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php could be useful for you.

Comment: is `$search` result a string? seems like it "keyword".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `$search` results will be a string, then you need to quote that variable in your query. I'm pretty sure that you're looking for a string in your database, seeing `echo "you didn't submit a keyword";` and `mess_username` being a user's "name".

```
WHERE mess_username='$search' ";
```

assuming an exact match. If you're looking for something that resembles your search, say you're looking for "foot" and want to find "football", then use LIKE.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` just in case there may be errors, and it seems that there would be, when not quoting a string in a query's variable.

Footnotes:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

Plus, it's best to use a conditional `empty()` against your input.

I.e.:

```
if(!empty($_POST[ 'mess_username' ])){
...
}
```

should someone just click without entering anything, which could throw you an error.

Comment: Just got my answer! Thanks very much everyone  and @Fred !

`WHERE mess_username='$search' ";`

Comment: Make sure to use % around your search param. SELECT 'David!' LIKE '%D%v%';

Answer (score 3):

You missed to quote your search term

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM messbd WHERE mess_username="' . mysql_real_escape_string($search) . '"';
```

But the mysql extension is **deprecated** and should be replaced by either PDO or mysqli. Here is an example with PDO and prepared statement:

```
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=server;dbname=my_db', 'user', 'pass', $options);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM messbd WHERE mess_username=?';
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($search));
// there is no sure working rowCount, so fetch all and count
$rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
if (!$rows) {
    echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b> $search </b>";
} else {
    echo count($rows) . " results found !<p>";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $mess_username = $row['mess_username'];
        $mess_email    = $row['mess_email'];
        $android_app   = $row['android_app'];
        echo "$mess_username<br>$mess_email<br>$android_app";
    }
}
```

Comment: Good use on the PDO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With this query mysql will search for $search input insted for the relarive value of the var. Try to use single quotes.